# How do i resolve: variable required value found (from textbook example)

Tags: java

so I'm doing an assignment currently where I am to make a program that specifies some characteristics of a body of text that is given from the user.

I am, for learning purpose, using examples from a book that was recommended for the course, it is online so I figured this would hopefully be a faster way to get an answer to my issue.

**The issue i get is:**
Error:(16, 33) java: unexpected type
required: variable
found:    value

So the code is as follows:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Text {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        String sentence = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a sentence: ");
        String letter = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a letter: ");

        int instances = 0;
        int place;
        for (place = 0; place < sentence.length(); place=place+1) {
            if (sentence.charAt (place) = letter) //searches for letter in sentence
                instances= instances + 1;
        }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,instances);
    }

}
```

The only difference between this code and the example from the textbook is that I added the letter variable, in the example the code searches for ' ' (blank space). But from what I gather both letter and  ' ' are in string, even though the letter is a variable.

Grateful for any help, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are not using the comparison operator `==` but instead you are using a simple `=` which is an assignment operator.

Second of all you are trying to compare a character (of type `char`) to a letter (of type `String`), which can't be done with the `==` operator.

You need to convert your letter to character somehow, for example with `charAt(0)`.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Text {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        String sentence = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a sentence: ");
        String letter = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a letter: ");

        int instances = 0;
        int place;
        for (place = 0; place < sentence.length(); place=place+1) {
            if (sentence.charAt (place) == letter.charAt(0)) //2 changes to your code are in this line.
                instances= instances + 1;
        }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,instances);
    }

}
```